# VS Code highlights first character

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

VS Code highlights first character in a file and gives this message "Plugin 'pylint_per_file_ignores' is impossible to load, is it installed ? ('No module named 'pylint_per_file_ignores'')PylintE0013:bad-plugin-value". Pylint is installed and I can't find anything named pylint_per_file_ignores. Google returns 0 results of this and so I do not know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the doc for this message](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/error/bad-plugin-value.html):

> One of your pylint plugins cannot be loaded. There's nothing to change
> in your code, but your pylint configuration or installation has an
> issue.
>
> For example, there might be a typo. The following config:
>
> [MAIN] load-plugins = pylint.extensions.bad_biultin
>
> Should be:
>
> [MAIN] load-plugins = pylint.extensions.bad_builtin
>
> Or the plugin you added is not importable in your environment.

Not importable in this case would mean you need to install https://pypi.org/project/pylint-per-file-ignores/ with `pip install pylint-per-file-ignores`

Comment: I swear I Googled pylint-per-file-ignores and there were no results. Apparently I did something super stupid